# Trouble showing queried data from sqlite to tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So I have this problem. The idea behind this little project is that I want to add up few columns from the SQLite database and depending on which checkboxes the user click on (those checkboxes are months and years) in the main GUI, display those results in an entry box, I can get the entry box to display something, but it's not what I want, instead, I get this message in the box: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x03DFC160>. All I want is to see the sum amount of the selected period.

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# Creates an entry widget
incomeentry = Entry(root) #
incomeentry.place(relx=0.89, rely =0.01, relheight=0.035, relwidth=0.1, bordermode='ignore')

#Sets check boxes either to int or to str
state5 = IntVar()
state6 = IntVar()
state7 = StringVar()
state8 = StringVar()

# Creates 4 check buttons (2 for years and 2 for months)
TCheckbutton1 = Checkbutton(root, variable=state5,onvalue=2019, offvalue=0)
TCheckbutton1.place(relx=0.62, rely=0.01, relwidth=0.03
, relheight=0.0, height=21)
TCheckbutton1.configure(text='''2019''')


TCheckbutton2 = Checkbutton(root, variable=state6,onvalue=2020, offvalue=0)
TCheckbutton2.place(relx=0.62, rely=0.03, relwidth=0.03
, relheight=0.0, height=21)
TCheckbutton2.configure(text='''2020''')


TCheckbutton3 = Checkbutton(root, variable=state7,onvalue='January', offvalue=0)
TCheckbutton3.place(relx=0.62, rely=0.05, relwidth=0.03
, relheight=0.0, height=21)
TCheckbutton3.configure(text='''January''')


TCheckbutton4 = Checkbutton(root, variable=state8,onvalue='February', offvalue=0)
TCheckbutton4.place(relx=0.62, rely=0.07, relwidth=0.03
, relheight=0.0, height=21)
TCheckbutton4.configure(text='''February'')



#Tries to connect to the database, queries data from the SQLite and inserts it into Tkinter entry box

def Choose():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("taxes.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    connect = c.execute("SELECT SUM(moneyback + woocomerce + deliveries) FROM income WHERE month = ? and year = ? ", (state7.get(), state6.get()))
    incomeentry.insert(0, connect)

    conn.close()


# Creates a button that executes the 'Choose' function

TButton1 = Button(root, command=Choose) 
TButton1.place(relx=0.54, rely=0.007, relwidth=0.075, relheight=0.00, height=50)
TButton1.configure(text='''Choose''')
```

So in general I want my summed amount from the 3 columns depending on the year and month that the user has clicked to appear in the empty entry box.

Comment: Try changing `incomeentry.insert(0, connect)` to `incomeentry.insert(0, connect.fetchone()[0])`.  Better delete the content of the entry before inserting the result.

Comment: Brilliant, something came up from here i can pick things up, thank you :)

Comment: @TheLowBudgetGangster should i add a detailed answer on this?

Comment: @Cool Cloud Would appreciate it, but as well could you give me some pointers, if for example i want to have multiple check boxes clicked, where should i start looking?

Comment: What about check boxes would you like to know

Comment: The thing is I made it so that by default it selects 2019 and January, how can I make so that the user could click any of those buttons and it would show different total income statements from any month or any year?

Comment: Actually you can use `state5.get()` to get the value of the entrybox and then use it inside of the `sql` statement. Keep in mind, that if the checkboxes are not ticked, itll give a sql error later on, i might recommend using `Combobox`

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code ...

```
connect = c.execute("SELECT SUM(moneyback + woocomerce + deliveries) FROM income WHERE month = ? and year = ? ", (state7.get(), state6.get()))
```

...will do the operation for searching the database for the favorable results and if you want to hold the results into a variable, you have to use `fetchall()` or `fetchone()` or `fetchmany()` method.

So something like,

```
results = connect.fetchall() #to fetch all the data
```

or

```
results = connect.fetchone() #to fetch one of the data
```

Note that `result` will be a list of tuples of data fetched.

Now you can insert by saying

```
incomeentry.insert(0, results[0]) #to insert the first item
```

[Here is some documentation on sqlite and python](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/)

[Some documentation on checkbuttons](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_checkbutton.htm)

Do let me know if any doubts, or errors

Cheers